# Purpose of short-circuit current value mentioned for ICs and op-amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, short-circuit

I've seen that in the datasheets of a few ICs, like CAN transceivers and low-power op-amps, there is a value mentioned as short-circuit current (short circuit between output and GND), which is usually around 100 mA.

What is the purpose of this current? Why do the manufacturers of these devices give this value to the users?
When a short circuit occurs, won't the IC get damaged?

Is there an example of when this value is useful while designing an application?

Comment: It depends on the specific device and application, but those numbers can be useful in determining trace sizing/wire selection/fusing for a worst-case scenario if you know that the internal circuitry of the device will limit current to a certain level.

Comment: It also gives you an idea of the "drive strength."  i.e., if you had to drive a kilometer-long wire, a driver spec'd at 10mA and 100mA output are going to have vastly different speed capabilities.

Comment: My thoughts for some would be to illustrate short circuit protection or thermal constraints (as in, maximum power to destruction).

Comment: Updated answer to include inputs as these also have current limits that need be be observed.

Comment: It's quite common that a short is conditionally safe, depending on ambient temperature and duration of the short circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data sheets usually give more than one value for this parameter.  An absolute maximum, a nominal maximum and a value that means the device remains within guaranteed specification.

There is no single answer to this as it depends on the device, it's use and it's misuse, also the environment you want to operate it in and the reliability levels you need to achieve.

Firstly there is an absolute maximum - current beyond this WILL almost certainly damage the IC pin or the entire IC by causing physical damage through migration of silicon dopants or evaporation of the tiny bond wires, right up to damaging the internal metalwork that routes power to various sub-circuits.

Then there is the output resistance.  An Imax parameter can use used to calculate the output resistance, so that a designer can predict how the output will behave under certain loads.

Lastly there can be an inbuilt current limit, either deliberate or as a practical upshot of the process technology within the device. This is usually implemented as a thermal feedback.  As you draw more current the output driver gets warm and reduces the current eventually it reaches a balance point where increasing the current gets so hot it cools again as the power dissipation drops, thus limiting the ultimate current to a constant (based on ambient temperature and thermal resistance of course)

Remember current can be caused by either a type of load that can itself produce no actual current of it's own or a load that can also produce a current.  So it's entirely possible that you can exceed the output current even though the load itself does not have a resistance or power dissipation to load the output beyond it's limit.

In all this there are three things to consider.  Normal operation, fault conditions and device stress. Dependent on the type of product, faults could be single or even multiple fault conditions. Even in normal operation a device that is less stressed will last longer without failing due to age. So if your product operates in a place that is not easy to get to or is of very high value, then you really need to avoid thermal limits even if the datasheet says they are ok. External interfaces are most at risk as you have less control over what can be done to them.

UPDATE:
For completeness is should be noted that inputs also have current limits as they will drive some sort of transistor gate (FET) or base (BJT) that itself has a maximum current, and there are usually deleberate or intrinsic diodes either to the rails or some other signals within the device either as a side effect of the design or deliberate additions to help prevent static damage. Like any (non-superconductor) these non-functional circuits have a current limit that if exceeded will cause failures that could impact the device operation.

Answer (score 1):

It is specified so you know it if you need it for something.

Short circuit to ground on op-amp or regulator either is destructive or it is not. It reads in the datasheet. Some op-amp could handle outputing 100mA into short circuit indefinitely, and another could be only 10mA and maximum safe time for short circuit is given.

If you make a device with user accessible terminals where user can accidentally make a short circuit, this helps you determine PCB track size which can handle the current, or put fuses or resistors or other current limiting devices on that wire.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit more complex than just a short circuit current, possibly leading to sustained damage due to heat, which is what the name implies.

The short circuit current is the maximum the device can sink or source while driving a heavy load.

From: [How much load can your operational amplifier drive?](https://www.eetimes.com/how-much-load-can-your-operational-amplifier-drive/) by Hashemi.

> The most common way to specify output drive is with the output short-circuit current parameter. The manufacturer specifies how much current is guaranteed to flow when the output is tied to ground.

> Two numbers may be given, one for sourcing (usually prefixed “+”) and one for sinking (usually prefixed “-“). The user can employ this number to predict the op amp behavior in applications where the voltage swing across the load is low, and therefore the output-stage drivers (internal to the op amp) maintain a large voltage headroom to the respective supply rails (V+ for sourcing current and V- for sinking current).

> Consider a case where an op amp is tied to a heavy load driven with a voltage close to ground (or Vs /2 in a single-supply case). If this amplifier stage is then hit with a step change, the amount of current that would be available to the load is what the data sheet calls the “output short-circuit current.”

> Once the output starts changing in response to the step, two things occur: The voltage headroom on the op amp's output voltage is reduced, and the op amp's input overdrive is reduced. In turn, the available output current is reduced due to the first factor and, depending on the op amp design, there may also be a reduction in output current due to the second factor.

You have to think about the opamp (or any device) as an output driving a load.

If we have a step change in a heavy load, the net effect is we get a large current as a sink (sinking current into device) or a source (sourcing current from device).

Figure 25 from [LMH664x Low Power, 130 MHz, 75 mA Rail-to-Rail Output Amplifiers](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmh6642.pdf?ts=1666994530420&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLMH6642)

[image]

Output current for this device is typically ±65mA.  Output short-circuit current is typically 95mA (sourcing) and 110mA sinking.  No maximums are given.  These are static numbers for a dynamic device.

Hashemi considers driving a 100Ω load as a source at 85°C (Figure 1) and uses the chart to go through a number of iterations using headroom [output voltage headroom (voltage difference relative to supply rails) to the respective supply voltage) to determine output current.

[image]

[image]

This 90mA is up from the typical 65mA and could be used to determine power dissipation.

From the LMH664x notes:

> (4) Output short circuit duration is infinite for \$V_S\$ < 6V at room temperature and below. For \$V_S\$ > 6V, allowable short circuit duration is 1.5ms.

Short-circuit current does not imply damage, but rather the power being delivered.

I must point out there are issues with Hashemi analysis since Figure 25 is \$V^+ = +5, V^− = −5V, R_F = R_L = 2 kΩ\$. Unless otherwise specified.  But Hashemi was a National Semiconductor application engineer and I bow to their expertise.